# How can I always display the placeholder in mat-select intependently of the current selection

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want the mat-select element to always show the placeholder, even if an option is selected.

My HTML code:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="'language'" placeholder="Language">
    <mat-option value="de">Deutsch</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="en">English</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The current behavior is: A soon as a language is selected, the placeholder is made small, moved to the top and the selected language is displayed is displayed big.

What I want to have: When a language is selected, still the placeholder should be displayed in big size, the selected language should not be shown.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a combination of `floatLabel="never"` and `mat-select-trigger`:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="'language'" placeholder="Language" floatlLabel="never">
    <mat-select-trigger>Language</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option value="de">Deutsch</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="en">English</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not providing a `label`, and in that case, "If not specified, the placeholder will be used as label." (from [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect)).

To disable it, provide a Label, and hide it.

```
<mat-label hidden></mat-label>
<mat-select [formControlName]="'language'" placeholder="Language">
    <mat-option value="de">Deutsch</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="en">English</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```